# How to add pagination to a single wordpress page with lot of text

Tags: pages, pagination

I create a new page in Wordpress and add a lot of text to it.  how to add pagination to this WP page??

I have tried using `<!––nextpage––>` which doesn't work in a page.

*most of the pagination solutions available are for posts or page in which multiple posts are fetched and displayed. I specifically have single page with lot of text which I need to split into paged view.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please read [How to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Amogh,

Do you mean that you want to split your article into pages? Maybe you can try page break tag like this: https://winningwp.com/how-to-insert-a-page-break-in-a-wordpress-post-or-page/

Switch to text editor and insert wherever you need to break page with code below:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: That works on a post, but it did not work on a page for me.